a Cyclic Quadrilateral Problem with two angle bisector
Let $ABCD$ is a cyclic quadrilateral and $E$ is the intersection point of $AC$ and $BD$. Let $P$ and $Q$ be points on $AC$ so that $A, E, Q, P, C$ lie on a straight line in that order; $BP$ and $DQ$ are the angle bisector of $\angle ABC$ and $\angle ADC$, respectively.
If $AE = 4, EQ = 2$, and $QP = 3$, then determine the length of $PC$.
By angle bisector property, $\frac{AB}{BC} = \frac{9}{PC}$ and $\frac{AD}{CD} = \frac{6}{3+PC}$.
Hence,
$$\frac{AB}{BC} + \frac{AD}{CD} = \frac{9}{PC} + \frac{6}{3+PC} = \frac{ABCD+ADBC}{BCCD}.$$
Now, by Ptolemy, $ABCD+ADBC=ACBD$. It means that $\frac{ACBD}{BCCD} = \frac{9}{PC} + \frac{6}{3+PC}$. Also, by Power of a Point, $AE\cdot EC = BE \cdot ED$.
Then, what's next? Now, I have no idea. Many thanks in advanced.

Essentially a repost of OP that was closed, though with a bit more working shown.

@CalvinLin So, what's the solution?

@CalvinLin ...? No solution????

You could add at least a figure. I'll give you a hint: triangles ABE and DEC are similar, and so are triangles AED and BEC.

From the similarity of triangles $ABE$ and $DEC$ we get $AB\cdot EC=DC\cdot EB$, while from the similarity of triangles $ADE$ and $BEC$ we get $BC\cdot EA=AD\cdot EB$. Dividing the first equality by the second one we thus obtain:
$$
{AB\over BC}\cdot{EC\over EA}={DC\over AD}.
$$
But the angle bisector theorem implies $AB/BC=AP/PC$ and $DC/AD=CQ/QA$. Inserting these into the above equality gives:
$$
{AP\over PC}\cdot{EC\over EA}={CQ\over QA}.
$$
Setting $PC=x$ this can be rewritten as
$$
{9\over x}\cdot{x+5\over 4}={x+3\over 6},
$$
which can be solved for $PC=x=15$.



Comment: Considering the fact that the perpendicular bisector of base and the bisector of vertex meet on circumcircle ,The extension of DQ meet the circle at J and that of BP meets it at G. GJ is the diameter of circle. As can be seen in the picture AC and BD cannot intersect at P, they  meet at point I which is about 5 unit from A. This construction says $PC\approx 11$ units.

To check, $AC$ and $BD$ intersect at $E$ and not $P$. So $PC \approx 11$ isn't that valid of a conclusion.
